# How do I find the hostname where my Grails app is running from within a service method?

Tags: grails, service

I was using request.getServerName() within a controller, but I'm moving my function into a service. How can I find the hostname where the app is running?

Comment: If you're deploying to a cloud service, good luck getting something reliable.  On the other hand, if you're deploying to known servers with known hosts, I'd just specify them in the Config and not even try and look them up dynamically.  Just pull the name from Config.

Comment: Can you give an example of setting static paths for dev vs deploy in config? I'll mark your answer.

Comment: (Setting in config and then reading from within a service method...)

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* that the service method will only ever be called from a controller action then you can use the Spring [`RequestContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) to get access to the current [`GrailsWebRequest`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/servlet/mvc/GrailsWebRequest.html), and from there the `request` object.  But you might be better off passing in the `request` from the controller or simply trusting `grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL` - ideally services shouldn't depend directly on web-tier classes.

If you need this info in a context where you can't use the injected `grailsApplication` (a constructor, field initializer or static method/closure) then you can access the config via `grails.util.Holders`.

Comment: I haven't had any luck using grailsApplication within a Service. I added def grailsApplication to the service but the variable is null when I call the method. I may also use the service from Bootstrap so I don't want to depend on a controller context.

Comment: I think Ian is suggesting that the code in question (in the Service) shouldn't be the thing to access what host the thing is running on.  Perhaps pass it into the Service with the call?  Would make this a lot more Test-able to do it that way, too.

Comment: That's a good approach - I've been trying it :)  But I need a way to get the hostname in BootStrap to pass it into the service.

Comment: @JoeBeuckman you definitely should be able to inject the `grailsApplication` into a service and access the config through that. You can't use injected dependencies in a _constructor_ but they definitely work in normal methods. Or failing that `grails.util.Holders.config` should work anywhere.